# Cross-referencing strings from two files by line number and collecting them into a third file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two files that I wish to coordinate into a single file for plotting an xy-graph.

File1 contains a different x-value on each line, followed by a series of y-values on the same line. File2 contains the specific y-value that I need from File1 for each point x.

In reality, I have 50,000 lines and 50-100 columns, but here is a simplified example.

File1 appears like this:

```
 1 15 2 3 1
 2 18 4 6 5
 3 19 7 8 9
 4 23 10 2 11
 5 25 18 17 16
```

- column 1 is the line number.
- column 2 is my x-value, sorted in ascending order.
- columns 3-5 are my y-values. They aren't unique; a y on one line could match a y on a different line.

File2 appears like this:

```
 3
 5
 2
 18
```

The y on each line in File2 corresponds to a number matching one of the y's in File1 from the same line (for the first few hundred lines).  After the first few hundred lines, they may not always have a match. Therefore, File2 has fewer lines than File1. I would like to either ignore these rows or fill it with a 0.

#### Goal

The output, File3, should consist of:

```
 15 3
 18 5
 19 0
 23 2
 25 18
```

or the line with

```
 19 0
```

removed, whichever works for the script. If neither option is possible, then I would also be okay with just matching the y-values line-by-line until there is not a match, and then stopping there.

#### Attempts

I initially routed File2 into an array:

```
  a=( $(grep -e '14,12|:*' File0 | cut -b 9-17) )
```

but then I noticed similar questions ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121222/identifying-genes-from-a-list-of-genes), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125155/compare-two-files-for-matching-lines-and-store-positive-results)) on Stackexchange used a second file, hence I routed the above grep command into File2.

These questions are slightly different, since I require specific columns from File1, but I thought I could at least use them as a starting point. The solutions to these questions:

1)

```
        grep -Fwf File2 File1
```

reproduces of course the entire line in File1, and I'm not sure how to proceed from there; or

2)

```
  awk 'FNR==NR {arr[$1];next} $1 in arr' File2 File1
```

fails entirely for me, with no error message except the general awk help response.

Is this possible to do? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please confirm if your output's last 2 lines `23 2` and `25 18` should have their `0` since their respective lines in file1 and file2 are not having values common.

Comment: They should not be 0. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR { arr[NR] = $1; next } {
    for (i = 3; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if ($i == arr[n]) {
            print $2, $i
            n++
            next
        }
    }
    print $2, 0
}' n=1 file2 file1
```

Comment: Hello. This seems to be very close, but it is double matching for me. For a given record, it stops at the first field > 3 in File1 that matches *any* string in File2. Is it possible to write the script so that it scans record 1, and stops at the first field which matches the string in record 1 from File2? Eventually, it will fail to find a match on the same record between File1 and File2, but it should be able to match the first few hundred records this way, which are the most important. Thank you.

Comment: This is more clear if you take my sample input and exchange the 2 and 1, so the first line reads: 1 15 2 3 1. My apologies the sample input wasn't prepared properly to check for this. I edited the OP to reflect this.

Comment: @Blaisem try it again, I think I managed to decipher your problem

Comment: You deciphered it perfectly. Thank you so much for your help. I spent all day trying to figure this out for a work project, and I probably never would have figured it out otherwise.

Comment: You're welcome. I really suck at English, that's why it took so long :D

Comment: No, my problem was confusing. It would have confused anyone. The fact you figured it out means your English is very good.

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`, will print the first match only

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} 
               {f2=$2; $1=$2=""; 
                for(k in a) if($0 FS ~ FS k FS) {print f2,k; next}}' file2 file1

15 2
18 5
23 2
25 18
```

padded `FS` to eliminate sub-string matches.  Note the order of the files, file2 should be provided first.

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately, I need to print the precise match. Line 1 from File1 must print the match with line 1 from File2. If there is no matching value in File2,  (so at 19 0 in File3), that's fine if everything after such a non-match is wrong. For the input I'm using, I don't expect a non-match until after several hundred lines of input, where it's not so much of an error for me. But I would definitely need the first points before a non-match to be correctly matched. But maybe this solution will help another reader in the future, so thank you for sharing.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong?  I commented that if there are multiple **y** value matches on a line this only prints the first **y** on the line.  So always there will be two fields on the output.  You wrote "I would like to either ignore these rows or fill it with a 0", so this script seems to do first.  Please explain what is wrong or provide a counter example showing it doesn't work.